# How to pass a string containing extended ascii chracters to an unmanaged C++ dll

Tags: c#, marshalling, unmanaged

I have a C# application that talks to a USB peripheral through a C DLL.

The C DLL implements a function :

```
long WriteText(char* data, long length);
```

If calling this from C/C++ I can send it regular ASCII text but also some extended characters such as '£' (0x9C hex).

However, I have wrapped this up in a C# class

```
[DllImport("c:\\USBPD.DLL", EntryPoint = "WriteText")]
public static extern int WriteText(string data, int length);
```

However, when I send it a string with a "£" I get a 'u^' in it's place. The rest of the string is fine. I have played around with the encoding types but still seem to be having problems.

Thank
Anand

Comment: What encoding C function expects in its `char* data` argument?

Comment: I'm pretty certain it's ASCII - but don't have the source as the dll is distributed as a binary driver from the hardware provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
[DllImport("c:\\USBPD.DLL")]
private static extern int WriteText([In] byte[] text, int length);

public static int WriteText(string text)
{
    Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(437); // 437 is the original IBM PC code page
    byte[] bytes = enc.GetBytes(text);
    return WriteText(bytes, bytes.Length);
}
```

Note that EntryPoint is not necessary if the name of the method is the same.

Comment: Wonderfull! The above worked great. I changed the encoding to Unicode which seemed to work.